# How can I filter multiple numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Refer to the image below:

[image: Student and Grade Excel]

If I want to filter the Column A with what I have in Column C, how do I do it ?
What I am saying is I only want to see the grades of students who made an A, and those are students 1,9,10, and 11. I cannot filter Grade. This is just a sample I created. I have a dataset with million data points.

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select whole column B by vlicking on B. then select " short & filter ". Where you will get an option called filter,click it.

now back on sheet you will see the dropdown list on the first cell in colum B. Select only " A" means by unselecting every thing else except "A".
That will only show the list of "A".

Is that what you want?
If it's not then let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. The question mentions the dataset has millions of rows. Your answer works if you only have a few things to select in column A, but what if the user has 500 labels they want to include?